# How to destruct values of expressions?

Tags: coq

I'm learning Coq and try to proof next seemingly simple property.
Basically, I need to consider all the cases for `eqb x y`,
but my usual approach using `destruct` and `induction` tactics fails here.

```
Fixpoint eqb (x:nat) (y: nat) :bool :=
match x,y with
| 0, 0 => true
| S xx, S yy => eqb xx yy
| _,_ => false
end.

Definition bool_to_nat (b:bool) :nat := 
  match b with
  | true => 1
  | false => 0
  end.

Theorem should_be_easy: forall x:nat, forall y : nat,
  bool_to_nat (eqb x y) + bool_to_nat (negb (eqb x y)) = 1.
  intros x y. Abort.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
intros x y.
destruct (eqb x y).
```

Comment: Wow! It's a pity most tutorials seem to only show destruct working on variables.